# Construction of a (3v-2,3,1)-BIBD

Tags: combinatorial-designs

I want to construct a 
$(3v - 2,3,1)$-BIBD from a 
$(v,3,1)$-BIBD and a quasigroup of order $v-1$.

**Attempt:** For new BIBD, firstly, I need $3v-2$ points. Let $A$ be a block in $(3v - 2,3,1)$-BIBD and 
$\left( {Y, \circ } \right)$ be a quasigroup of order $v-1$. I define the points as 
${Y_1} = \left\{ {Y \times A} \right\} \cup \infty $. Then, 
$\left| {{Y_1}} \right| = 3v - 2$. Now, I need to define the blocks for new BIBD. But it seems that there is a problem here because, by such a definition for points, I don't use $(3v - 2,3,1)$-BIBD.

That is, I'm on stuck. I'll be pleasure if one gives a hint for solution.

Comment: What is a BIBD?

Comment: A 
$\left( {v,k,\lambda } \right)$-BIBD is a $2-\left( {v,k,\lambda } \right)$ design where 
$v \ge k$.

Comment: BIBD is balanced incomplete block design.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal{D} = (V,\mathcal{A})$ be your $(v,3,1)$-BIBD, and $(Y,\circ)$ be your quasigroup. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $Y\subset V$ and that $V = Y\cup \{r\}$. Furthermore, let $\mathcal{A}^\ast:=\{A\in\mathcal{A}\;|\;r\in A\}$ and $\hat{\mathcal{A}}:=\mathcal{A}\setminus\mathcal{A}^\ast$.

Next, define $W:=\{r\}\cup(Y\times\{1,2,3\})$ and

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{B}_1&:=\bigl\{\;\{r, (s, k), (t, k)\}\;|\;\{r,s,t\}\in\mathcal{A}^\ast,\;k\in\{1,2,3\}\;\bigr\}\\
\mathcal{B}_2&:=\bigl\{\;\{(s,k), (t, k), (u, k)\}\;|\;\{s,t,u\}\in\hat{\mathcal{A}},\;k\in\{1,2,3\}\;\bigr\}\\
\mathcal{B}_3&:=\bigl\{\;\{(s,1), (t, 2), (s\circ t, 3)\}\;|\;s,t\in Y\;\bigr\}
\end{align}
$$

Then it is not too difficult to see that $(W,\mathcal{B}_1\cup\mathcal{B}_2\cup\mathcal{B}_3)$ is in fact a $(3v-2,3,2)$-BIBD.